# Testcafe reporter inside script

Tags: automated-tests, reporting, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Is it possible to add a reporter to a TestCafe js File? 
Common usage is:

```
testcafe chrome 'path/to/test/file.js' --reporter allure
```

But is it also possible to add this to the script itself? In my script I have

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Ordner erstellen`
    .page `https://bc3-channel.cliplister.com/`;

//It is absolutely necessary that the names are completely unique for finding elements.


test('Create and Delete Folder', async t => {
   .click(Selector('span').withText('Login'))
});
```

Can I add a section inside the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [TestCafe Programming Interface](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/) and its [reporter property](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#reporter) for this purpose.

However, I'm not sure what 'section' you'd like to add. Please clarify this.